# Determining first eigenvalue of Sturm Liouville problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, sturm-liouville

Show that the Sturm Liouville problem given by $$u''+ \lambda xu=0$$ on the interval $[0,1]$ satisfying the boundary conditions $u(0)=u(1)+u'(1)=0$ has no negative eigenvalues.

I have tried computing the Rayleigh quotient $$ \frac{\int_{0}^{1} uu'' dx}{\int_{0}^{1} xu^2 dx}$$ but this gives me a negative value because of the boundary conditions and I can't prove what I want.

Any help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $u$ is an eigenfunction, then $\lambda$ is real, $u$ may be assumed to real, and
\begin{align}
   \lambda\int_{0}^{1}xu^2dx & = -\int_{0}^{1}u''udx \\
    & = -u'u|_{0}^{1}+\int_{0}^{1}u'^2dx \\
    & = -u'(1)u(1)+u'(0)u(0)+\int_{0}^{1}u'^2dx \\
    & = u(1)^2 +\int_{0}^{1}u'^2 dx
\end{align}
Therefore $\lambda \ge 0$ must hold.